# copying void pointer to another void pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, heap-memory, void-pointers

I am trying to copy a void pointer to different indexes of another pointer array, things work fine for characters but there appears problem for integer and doubles

Here is my strcture:

```
typedef struct vector_struct {
 size_t e_sz;
 char e_type;

 #define V_INT 1 
 #define V_DOUBLE 2
 #define V_CHAR 3

 unsigned no_e;
 unsigned cur_cap;
 void* e_array;

}* vector_type;
 //for typecasting
  #define vector_int_at(v,i) (*((int*)v_at(v,i)))
  #define vector_double_at(v,i) (*((double*)v_at(v,i)))
  #define vector_char_at(v,i) (*((char*)v_at(v,i)))

  void* v_at(vector_type v, iterator i) {
    if ( v == NULL )
     fail("v_at() Error: no such vector");
    if ( i == iterator_end )
     i = v->no_e -1;
    if ( i < 0 || i >= v->no_e )
     fail("v_at() Error: no such element in this vector");
    return (v->e_array+i); //return element
   }
```

I want to copy value into the `void* e_array` , it can be either integer, character or a double.

```
void v_push_back(vector_type v, void* new_val){
 if ( v->no_e >= v->cur_cap ) {
    /*** need to expand the array ***/
    v->cur_cap += (v->cur_cap)? v->cur_cap : 2;

    v->e_array = check_a(realloc(v->e_array, sizeof(void*) * v->cur_cap));
    //allocate memory

   }
/*** copy new_val into the array at end position (v->no_e) ***/
   printf("%d  %d %p\n",v->e_sz,v->no_e,v->e_array+(v->no_e *v->e_sz));
    memcpy(
          v->e_array +(v->no_e)*v->e_sz,
          new_val,
          v->e_sz
          );

 (v->no_e)++;
}
```

I have called this function like this:

```
c1 = 'o'; v_push_back(vc1,(void*)&c1); //for character
for ( i1 = 0 ; i1 < 10 ; i1++ ){ //for integer
    v_push_back(vi1,(void*)&i1);
}

//I call these like
  for ( i1 = 0 ; i1 < vector_size(vi1) ; i1++ )
   printf(" %ld",vector_int_at(vi1,i1));
  printf("\n");
```

But it seems things doesn't work for integer but works well for characters but for integers garbage values are copied as shown:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OELzo.png)

Please help me out. thanks

Here the complete project:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/assignment.pointers.vectorc.implementation/C-VectorImplementation1.zip

Comment: When reading, do you cast `e_array`? If yes how?

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Comment: You're probably not taking account of the size of what your void pointer points to. Anyway please provide a [mcve].

Comment: #define vector_int_at(v,i) (*((int*)v_at(v,i)))
#define vector_double_at(v,i) (*((double*)v_at(v,i)))
#define vector_char_at(v,i) (*((char*)v_at(v,i)))

Comment: @FaizanShah: Do not put code in comments. Edit the question to contain a [mcve].

Comment: You are always allocating `sizeof(void *)`  -- `v->e_array = check_a(realloc(v->e_array, sizeof(void*) * v->cur_cap));` perhaps you want `v->e_array = check_a(realloc(v->e_array, v->e_sz * v->cur_cap));` size of current vector.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (emphasis on _complete_). Something that can be copy/pasted and compiled.

Comment: @FaizanShah what is the `v_at` function? (And yes, edit you question!)

Comment: here is the path to actual project:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/assignment.pointers.vectorc.implementation/C-VectorImplementation1.zip

Comment: @Phantom edited

Comment: @FaizanShah No one is going to follow a link to an external zip file.  The code should be posted **as text** in the question.  If the code is too long, then you need to focus on the "Minimal" part of a MCVE by trimming it down to a sample that reproduces your problem.

Comment: The code in the linked ZIP file does not match the code in the question. In the ZIP file, `v_push_back` contains `if(v->e_type==V_INT){…`. In the question, it does not. Obviously, one should never expect to get a correct answer why code X is not working by asking about code Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few problems I see,

1. In order to get ith location of current vector type you need to multiply `i` with `v->e_sz`.

   ```
   void* v_at(vector_type v, iterator i)
   {
       .....
       return ((char*)v->e_array+i*v->e_sz); //return element    
   }
   ```
2. You are allocating `sizeof(void *)` what you want is

   ```
    v->e_array = check_a(realloc(v->e_array, v->e_sz * v->cur_cap));
   ```
3. Also as of now you are storing address as `int` but you need to store its value.

   ```
   void v_push_back(vector_type v, void* new_val){
        if(v->e_type==V_INT){
           //  (v->e_array+(v->no_e))=new_val;
           ((int*)v->e_array)[v->no_e]=*(int*)new_val;
                                       ^------storing its content
        }
   }
   ```

   Without any type checks, simple `memcpy` should work.

   ```
   void v_push_back(vector_type v, void* new_val){
       ....
       memcpy(
             v->e_array +(v->no_e)*v->e_sz,
             new_val,
             v->e_sz
             );
          //   *(char*)(v->e_array+v->no_e)=*(char*)new_val;

        (v->no_e)++;
    }
   ```